# Key can't be used to index type when it should

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, type-inference

I've got the following TS code

```
type Fruit = { kind: "apple" } | { kind: "grape"; color: "green" | "black" };
type FruitTaste<TFruit extends Fruit> = TFruit["kind"] extends "apple"
  ? "good"
  : TFruit["color"] extends "green"
  ? "good"
  : "bad";
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigbygayQOwBMAuKAIgEMwwAbCMqAXygB8tcCTyBzOK+gNxQAxgHsaouKTK8IEfAzZkARjQrCcDRgIBQoSLEQoAKhQDOwCAB5j8ZKggAPS0TOH7APnRRbR4AG0yPCIyAF0oJxdCN0pqOjIdKCgAfh5RUUIEpNJfe0CxCTgwiOd5aJ44OQVElLSMrKhpZQpMgSA)

It errors at `TFruit["color"]` with

```
Type '"color"' cannot be used to index type 'TFruit'.
```

but it shouldn't, because we're in the ternary side where `TFruit` should only be restricted to `{ kind: "grape"; color: "green" | "black" }`, and the `color` key should exist.

Weirdly enough TS doesn't have to have any issue with the "runtime" version of it:

```
type Fruit = { kind: "apple" } | { kind: "grape"; color: "green" | "black" };
const fruitTaste = (fruit: Fruit) =>
  fruit.kind === "apple" ? "good" : fruit.color === "green" ? "good" : "bad";
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigbygayQOwBMAuKAIgEMwwAbCMqAXygB8tcCTyBzOK+gNxQAxgHsaouKTK8IEfAzZkARjQrCcDRgIBQY-AGdUAM0QoAKhSPQMAClPJgpeI4CU6AHw6oUBygB0eEToaBiU1HQMAPw8oqKEDKR+wP5iEnAhYbLy0bHxieTKFAm6QA)

Why is that? How can I implement the `FruitTaste` type?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can implement it by seperating the type `{ kind: "apple" }` and `{ kind: "grape"; color: "green" | "black" }`.

```js
type Apple = { kind: "apple" };
type Grape = { kind: "grape"; color: "green" | "black" };
type Fruit = Apple | Grape;
type FruitTaste<TFruit extends Fruit> = TFruit extends Grape
    ? TFruit["color"] extends "green"
        ? "good"
        : "bad"
    : "good";
```

Comment: Nice workaround! Works in my case, so upvoted. Doesn't answer the question of *why* TS doesn't like my code though. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1):

To the "why" question: TypeScript does not discriminante unions in generic conditionals based on specific properties. `TFruit` can not be indexed because at the point of this check, `TFruit` is still a union with two elements of which one does not have a `color` property.

My workaround would look like this:

```
type FruitTaste<TFruit extends Fruit> = TFruit extends { kind: "apple" }
  ? "good"
  : (TFruit & { color: string })["color"] extends "green"
    ? "good"
    : "bad";
```

Before accessing `color`, we can use an intersection to remind TypeScript that this property should exist.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigbygayQOwBMAuKAIgEMwwAbCMqAXygB8tcCTyBzOK%20gNxQAxgHsaouKTK8IEfAzZkARjQrCcDRgIBQO0JFiIUAFQoBnYBAA8J%20MlQQAHlaLmjDgHzood445d5QndsPCJpKlp6Jh0oKAB%20HlFRQjJYqFIACj8HKAAydjEJKShLOAJuJgBKAG0yIskyAF0oZ1dgnjg5BXS4xJlk1N6M8mUKVN0gA)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround, thanks to [Matt Pocock on Twitter](https://twitter.com/mattpocockuk/status/1546408069546086401):

```
TFruit["color"] extends "green"
```

does not properly disambiguate the union, but

```
TFruit extends { color: 'green' }
```

does, and this compiles properly

```
type Fruit = { kind: "apple" } | { kind: "grape"; color: "green" | "black" };
type FruitTaste<TFruit extends Fruit> = TFruit["kind"] extends "apple"
  ? "good"
  : TFruit extends { color: 'green' }
  ? "good"
  : "bad";
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigbygayQOwBMAuKAIgEMwwAbCMqAXygB8tcCTyBzOK+gNxQAxgHsaouKTK8IEfAzZkARjQrCcDRgIBQoSLEQoAKhQDOwCAB5j8ZKggAPS0TOH7APnRRbR4AG0yPCIyAF0oJxdCN0pqOjIdKCgAfh5RUUIEpNJfewjneWj2MQkpKAByWXlypkSUtIysqGllCkyBIA)